# Generics errors using Guava's toImmutableSortedMap collector from Kotlin

Tags: generics, kotlin, java-stream, guava

I'm trying to use Guava's `toImmutableSortedMap` collector from Kotlin 1.3.50 (on Java 13 on macOS 10.14.6 + updates).  I get generics errors whenever I try to use `toImmutableSortedMap`, but I don't get any errors if I use `toImmutableMap` instead:

```
val map = mutableMapOf<String, MutableMap<Path, String>>()

// populate map

// toImmutableSortedMap has compile-time generics errors
map.entries.stream()
.collect(
    toImmutableSortedMap<Map.Entry<String, MutableMap<Path, String>>, String, ImmutableSortedMap<Path, String>>(
        naturalOrder<String>(),
        {it.key},                             // errors e1 & e2 here
        {ImmutableSortedMap.copyOf(it.value)} // errors e3 & e4 here
    )
)

// toImmutableMap works fine
map.entries.stream()
.collect(
    toImmutableMap<Map.Entry<String, MutableMap<Path, String>>, String, ImmutableSortedMap<Path, String>>(
        {it.key},
        {ImmutableSortedMap.copyOf(it.value)}
    )
)
```

Generics errors for `toImmutableSortedMap`:

```
e1: Type mismatch: inferred type is () -> [ERROR : <ERROR PROPERTY TYPE>] but Function<in Map.Entry<String, MutableMap<Path, String>>!, out String!>! was expected
e2: Unresolved reference: it
e3: Type mismatch: inferred type is () -> ??? but Function<in Map.Entry<String, MutableMap<Path, String>>!, out ImmutableSortedMap<Path, String>!>! was expected
e4: Unresolved reference: it
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add some types explicitly and it will work:

```
map.entries.stream()
    .collect(
        toImmutableSortedMap<Map.Entry<String, MutableMap<Path, String>>, String, ImmutableSortedMap<Path, String>>(
            naturalOrder<String>(),
            Function { it.key },                             
            Function { ImmutableSortedMap.copyOf(it.value) } 
        )
    )
```

For me it looks like some issues with SAM conversions in Kotlin